# How to run a timer in the Background

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I wanna create a mobile apps using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation. The app  should have a timer, and when I close the application, timer still running. So if the apps has not been used for long time, it will uninstall itself. I hope can get a draft idea how to make it, now I cannot find any material about it (API or others....). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in MobileFirst Platform Foundation, and in general, to have an application *uninstall itself*. At the very least you could write a service in Android to do the timer, but not in iOS (maybe only in iOS 8 with app extensions), but still - your scenario is not valid. An application cannot uninstall itself.